# Can't login in admin panel through firefox and chrome (Opera is fine)

Tags: admin, admin-login, chrome-browser, ce-1.9.2.2

Suddenly I can't no longer access the admin panel from chrome and firefox with magento 1.9.2.2, however chrome is fine.

Settings(Magento url: `www[dot]farmaciacaloini[dot]com[slash]shop`):

```
web/session/use_http_via                0
web/session/use_http_x_forwarded_for    0
web/session/use_http_user_agent         1
admin/security/use_form_key             1

admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime  86400
web/default/cms_no_cookies              enable-cookies
web/cookie/cookie_lifetime              86400
web/cookie/cookie_path                  [slash]shop
web/cookie/cookie_domain                [dot]farmaciacaloini[dot]com
web/cookie/cookie_httponly              0
web/cookie/cookie_restriction           1
```

Observation:

- If the credentials are wrong then the message shows up
- If the credentials are corect the page quickly refreshes and deletes all the cookies
- I have cleaned session and cache folders and memcache and mod_pagespeed cache
- The hidden input `form_key` is present
- It has worked since some days ago, I haven't done any changes to cookies setting, maybe I have changed some values to the security option, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `mod_pagespeed`.
I have tried to disable the core and progressively enable filters to find out the problem, without success, so I had to completely disable it.